# Enable access to post images in the API, for "Stack Overflow for Teams"

Tags: feature-request, api, stack-overflow-for-teams

The Stack Exchange API supports access to [Stack Overflow for Teams](https://stackoverflow.com/teams); see the [*Teams* API documentation](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/teams).

But, since Teams content is private, post images aren't uploaded to imgur.com, but instead hosted on the Teams server. The resulting URLs look like this:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/c/[team name]/images/s/[guid].png
```

and they can only be accessed via the browser when you're logged in.

It looks like they cannot be accessed via the API and, unlike normal post images, can't be fetched with a simple `GET`.

Please add a route for an API client to download these post images.